# mysql - For every MODEL how many PIECES are in the database?

Tags: mysql

I have a CAR table and I want to know for every MODEL how many PIECES are in the database? (Model contains also sub models but all together it is fine).
So far:

```
SELECT MODEL DM, MODEL CM
FROM CAR 
WHERE DM = (DISTINCT MODEL)
AND CM = (COUNT MODEL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i am misunderstanding you but wouldn't this solve your problem:

```
SELECT MODEL , COUNT(*)
FROM CAR 
GROUP BY MODEL ;
```

If you want to count the number of distinct values for a column because there might be several entries for a single value you can use this:

```
SELECT MODEL , COUNT(DISTINCT YOUR_COLUMN_NAME)
FROM CAR 
GROUP BY MODEL ;
```